# Angular Nested Forms Error - Cyclic Object Value

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I have a parent form, and a child for within a main component. I am trying to get the main component to read the data from the parent form, but am getting an error: `cyclic object value` in the console.

My guess is that it is the parent form being defined in `form-one` and `form-two`, but I don't know how to do the following:

1) create a nested reactive form (form-two) that is shared with the
        parent form (form-one)
2) Allow the main component to access the
        form value of the parent and nested form.

My stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkddez

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you're seeing is because you're applying the json pipe to a form group, which just isn't going to work because it has a recursive structure that can't be represented in string. apply it to the value:

```
{{formComponent.parentForm?.value | json }}
```

if you want all components to use the same form group, then make sure you're actually passing it to your sub component:

```
<app-form-two [parentForm]="parentForm"></app-form-two>
```